# Why does the Sun have different day lengths, but not the gas giants?

Tags: the-sun, rotation, gas-giants

The [Sun's rotation period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_rotation) varies from about 25 days at the equator to about 38 days at the poles. As I understand it, this is because the Sun is not solid, and because of the way centripetal force works, the equator must move faster than the poles.

Question: if this works, why do Jupiter/Saturn/Uranus/Neptune have well-defined days? Why don't the equators of these planets rotate faster than the poles as well? For example, [Wikipedia's article on Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter) gives the length of a Jovian day as 9h 55m 30s, which is so precise that it implies Jupiter does not have a rotational period which varies with latitude.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's a matter of how "day" is defined.

Wikipedia's article on Jupiter cites [this IAU/IAG paper](http://www.hnsky.org/iau-iag.htm) for the length of a Jupiter day.  In it, footnote (e) of table I has the following:

> The equations for W for Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune refer to the rotation of their magnetic fields (System III)

The radio emissions of the gas giants have well-defined periodic variations.  These variations are caused by the rotation of the magnetic fields of those planets, and are evidence that they have a reasonably coherent core of some sort that's rotating at a uniform speed.  The periodic variations then represent the rotation speed of that object, which is taken as the rotation speed of the planet.

We're reasonably certain the Sun *doesn't* have a coherent core.  Measuring the variation of the magnetic field doesn't show a well-defined period, and doesn't provide a useful definition of the Sun's rotation speed.

Comment: I just add that for Jupiter there is definitively no a fix day based on std rotation. At least no for the outer layer. It does even rotate in stripes and a simulation as in Celestia package is a kind of spectacle.

Comment: “The assumption is that whatever's generating the magnetic field forms a reasonably coherent mass that's rotating at a uniform speed.” — I’d strengthen this by pointing out that it’s not just an assumption, it’s based closely on empirical facts: the magnetic field has a measurable uniform periodic behaviour, and based our understanding of planetary magnetic fields, we’re confident this corresponds to rotation of a somewhat coherent core.  With the sun, as I understand it, we don’t see *any* uniformly periodic behaviour that we would expect to correspond to some kind of rotating mass.

Comment: The [Sun's magnetic field](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2016/picturing-the-sun-s-magnetic-field) don't have a period as @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine stated.